# How can I disable content elements in typo3 9.5?

Tags: typo3, element, disable

Is there a way to hide content elements on content add that aren't being used anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

what kind of users should not see them?

*Usual users solution*

- Create a backend user group an remove all the unwanted elements from their rights
- Find the official manual for that in [TYPO3 Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/9.5/en-us/UserManagement/Groups/Index.html)

*Global solution*

Remove them by editing Page-TSConfig like this:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
 removeItems = header, text, textpic, image, bullets, table, uploads, media, mailform, search, login, menu, shortcut, html, script, splash, div, list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see documentation https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/UsingSetting/Index.html, how to set TSConfig

see documentation how to change the View of the TYPO3-backend with TSConfig
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

To prevent configuration-conflicts with other extensions use the TSConfig-function `addToList` in Page-TSCsconfig. List of Content-Elements in TYPO3 11:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
# dont remove contentelement 'textmedia'
# remove the other Contentelements in TYPO3 11
        removeItems  := addToList(header, text, textpic, image,  bullets, table, uploads, menu_abstract, menu_categorized_content, menu_categorized_pages, menu_pages, menu_subpages, menu_recently_updated, menu_related_pages, menu_section, menu_section_pages, menu_sitemap, menu_sitemap_pages, form_formframework, felogin_login, shortcut, list, div, html)

    }
```